# Save changes in Theme Editor of Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

In the version 1.4 of Android Studio was introduced the **Theme Editor** to simply color settings of theme.

[image]

It's quite simple customize colors, but i don't known how to save changes to colors.xml file. Is Anyone gots same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well your question isn't very clear so correct me if am wrong, you want to save changes of a color made by the theme editor to a color.xml file? 
This by default is saved and your not required to create a color.xml file but 
If you still want to get the color resource value, you can just get the color resource value when you select a "new color using the theme editor" then save the color value in your color.xml file. 
There you can reference it in your code.